# How do I add polyline length to a Bing Maps polygon

Tags: bing-maps, polyline

I am trying to recreate a tax map within my system using Bing Maps. My problem is in listing the length, in feet, of the sides of the polygons I am creating. I have a good idea of how to get the length of polylines I am creating from the MSSQL 2012 geometry or geography items in my database. I cannot figure out how to present it to the user effectively though. I have two ideas for how I would like to do this.

1. Place the lengths directly on or adjacent to the polyline in question.
2. Create an emphasized point on the full polygon and list to the side of the map, the lengths of the sides of the polygon based on a clockwise order.

Either of the 2 options would work as an acceptable solution. I used this tutorial to create my current environment so I would be looking to integrate the solution into it in some way:
[How to create a spatial web service that connects a database to Bing Maps using EF5](http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/07/31/how-to-create-a-spatial-web-service-that-connects-a-database-to-bing-maps-using-ef5/)
Note that my implementation only uses the countries part of the code so I do not need to deal with single points like cities that are in that tutorial.

The relevant piece of code that handles drawing on the map that I would need to edit can be found here:
[Bing Maps v7 WellKnowTextModule](http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BMv7Plugins/BMv7.WellKnowText/scripts/WKTModule.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the perimeter of a polygon in SQL2012 you can grab the exterior ring of it. The exterior ring will be a LineString i.e. "@g.STExteriorRing()". Then measure the length along that line. i.e. "@g.STExteriorRing().STLength()". However, countries are usually not just single Polygons, they can be MultiPpolygons, or GeometryCollections. So to calculate these lengths we have to do a bit more work. Here is a helper method you can add to the service to calculate the perimeters of these shapes:

```
private double CalculateLength(SqlGeometry geom)
{
    double length = 0;

    if(string.Compare(geom.STGeometryType().Value, "polygon", true) == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (string.Compare(geom.STGeometryType().Value, "multipolygon", true) == 0)
    {
        int numPolygon = geom.STNumGeometries().Value;
        for(int i = 1; i <= numPolygon; i++){
            length += geom.STGeometryN(i).STExteriorRing().STLength().Value;
        }                
    }
    else if (string.Compare(geom.STGeometryType().Value, "geometrycollection", true) == 0)
    {
        int numGeom = geom.STNumGeometries().Value;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numGeom; i++)
        {
            length += CalculateLength(geom.STGeometryN(i));
        }
    }

    return length;
}
```

To get the length info from the server side to the client add a property to the Country or BaseEntity class like this:

```
[DataMember]
public double Perimeter { get; set; }
```

From here you can populate this value after the linq query is used to get the response results using a simple loop that calls the helper method from earlier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < r.Results.Count;i++)
{
    var geom = SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(r.Results[i].WKT), 4326);
    r.Results[i].Perimeter = CalculateLength(geom);
}
```

As for displaying the information on the map. An easy way to place the information on a polyline is to choose a coordinate along the line, perhaps the middle one, just get the # or coordinates in the line and find the middle index and use that coordinate for a pushpin. You can then create a custom push using either a background image with text, or using custom HTML:

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins4

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins15

Comment: I ended up going with the html tags for labeling the distance. there is some problem with it taking up too much space at single digit zoom levels but a toggle button should work for the issue hopefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add an addendum to the answer I accepted as I feel it changes it a bit.

While working on this I found that I was not actually able to get each line segment's length via entity framework. This is due to the fact that the query required changing the geography I had back to a geometry then parse it to its base line segments and then change those line segments back to geographies. The query, even in SQL, would take minutes so it was not an option to run dynamically in EF.

I ended up creating another table in my database containing the parsed line segments for each side of each polygon I had. Then I could use the centroids of the line segments as faux cities. I then added this logic into the DisplayData javascript function from the tutorial mentioned in the question after the for loop in the method.

```
if (shape.getLength) {
  } else {
    var chkPolygon = data.Results[0].WKT.substring(0, data.Results[0].WKT.indexOf('(', 0));
    chkPolygon = chkPolygon.replace(/\s/g, '');

    switch (chkPolygon.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'point':

      case 'polygon':
        var latlonCheck = map.getCenter();
        var setSides = window.location.origin + "/SpatialService.svc/FindNearBy?latitude=" +
          latlonCheck.latitude + "&longitude=" + latlonCheck.longitude +
          "&radius=" + data.Results[0].ID + "&layerName=" + "city" + "&callback=?";

        CallRESTService(setSides, DisplaySides);
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

the data.Results[0].ID would find all the line segments in the new table for that specific country. Then the DisplaySides function is used to overlay the html pushpins as "cities" over the appropriate points for each side on the map

```
function DisplaySides(getSides) {
  infobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
  if (getSides && getSides.Results != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < getSides.Results.length; i++) {
      var sideLenFtShort = Math.round(getSides.Results[i].LengthFeet * 100) / 100;
      var htmlLenString = "<div style='font-size:14px;border:thin solid black;background-color:white;font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + sideLenFtShort.toString(); + "</div>";
      var testString = {
        pushpinOptions: { width: null, height: null, htmlContent: htmlLenString }
      };
      var sideCtr = WKTModule.Read(getSides.Results[i].WKT, testString);

      dataLayer.push(sideCtr);
    }
  }
  else if (getSides && getSides.Error != null) {
    alert("Error: " + getSides.Error);
  }
}
```